# Reasons for CCButton to not react/swallow touch?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCButton, which is initialised with two images, normal and pressed.

Problem is, when I touch the button, it reacts, the images are changing, but nothing else happens. I have set a selector, and it doesn't fire it up. When I log the location of the touch, it shows up in the console wherever I touch, except when I touch the button - it's like the button swallows touch but does nothing.

What could be a reason for this kind of behaviour? The button reacts, it changes states of unpressed/pressed, but it does not execute given selector and when pressed, location does not get logged in the console.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot give any code because it is from a project we are making, but really, there is nothing special in the code, everything is standard use of Cocos2D. I only asked if someone knows some reasons that could be a source of this problem, some standard ones, for example, if some component could be swallowing touches or something. Anyway, we solved problem by removing CCButton and using CCSprite with two images (normal and pressed) and finding intersection of touch and sprite.